# How to get back the missing monitor option in Mountain Lion's menubar?

Tags: macos, display, screen, menu-bar

When plugging in an external monitor on every OS X < 10.8 you could set the monitor options to show up on the menu bar.

How do I get this option on Mountain Lion?

I connect a DVI monitor via the hdmi ouput on a retina MacBook Pro and I am unable to find a way to enable this option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

System>Library>Coreservices>Menu Extras - Double click on the Displays.Menu icon

Just like in the old (10.3?) days.

Comment: this actually gets you the option back in the menubar(even though it is a different symbol) knowing the shortcut is however better in my opinion.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut is very good... providing you have a newer Apple keyboard. If not, you're out of luck.

Comment: @CarlosTheBadger I tried your tips but the icon appear for a second and then disappear again. I have a MacBook Pro 2011, and I'm attaching a VGA monitor.

Comment: Now that it is available through a menu, you could map a shortcut key to it.  Still, a functional menu would actually be useful.  The Displays.menu thing just displays a menu to open the Displays preferences.  Pretty lame, actually.

Answer (score 12):

[Display Menu](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12) (free) on the Mac App store adds the menu options back for OS X 10.8

Answer (score 11):

The menubar option is not available anymore.

You have to go into System Preferences > Displays.

THe fastest way is to use shortcuts:

**Option(alt) + Brightness Key** on an Apple Keyboard brings you directly to the display settings.
**Command + F1** to toggle between video mirroring and extended desktop
**Command + F2** to detect displays

**Control + Brightness** to change the brightness of the secondary display.

Comment: What I find missing is being able to quickly change the resolution. This is too many steps now and I don't understand what motivation Apple had for removing the menubar icon.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Change for the sake of change.

Answer (score 4):

I did find out that in Display Preferences, if you hold down <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> you get the detect display. The the other solution of using <kbd>⌥</kbd> + Brightness keys works.